# Call methods from the Activity class (React Native Android)

Tags: android, react-native, reactjs

Is there an api to call methods from the `Activity` class? I need to call `finish()` on my app but couldn't find anything relevant in the docs.

To be more specific, I want to `finish()` the `MainActivity` from my index.android.jsx, when a particular `TouchableHighlight` is pressed.

[update]

For now I'm exposing a `finish()` method from my NativeModule but maybe there's a better way to do that.

https://github.com/sneerteam/react-native-sneer/blob/master/src/main/java/me/sneer/react/SneerModule.java#L84

Comment: You can call finish() in the activity class in order to destroy the activity. Is that what you're asking?

Comment: No, I want to call it from a React Native component on my index.android.jsx

Comment: did you find any solution for this @buenoFelipe i have same issue

Comment: FYI, if all you're trying to do is `finish()` the React Native Activity then you can import `BackAndroid` from `react-native` and then use `BackAndroid.exitApp()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see a built in way to do this either and your approach using `NativeModule` is what I use as well.

However, if you call `setCurrentActivity` when building your `ReactInstanceManager` then you can call `getCurrentActivity` from your module instead of passing it through the `ReactPackage` and `ReactModule` constructors.

**MyReactModule.java**

```
public class MyReactModule extends ReactContextBaseJavaModule {

    public MyReactModule(ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
        super(reactContext);
    }

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return getClass().getSimpleName();
    }

    @ReactMethod
    public void finish() {
        Activity activity = getCurrentActivity();
        if (activity != null) {
            activity.finish();
        }
    }

}
```

**MyReactPackage.java**

public class MyReactPackage implements ReactPackage {

```
    @Override
    public List<Class<? extends JavaScriptModule>> createJSModules() {
        return Collections.emptyList();
    }

    @Override
    public List<ViewManager> createViewManagers(ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
        return Collections.emptyList();
    }

    @Override
    public List<NativeModule> createNativeModules(ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
        List<NativeModule> modules = new ArrayList<>();
        modules.add(new MyReactModule(reactContext));
        return modules;
    }

}
```

**ReactInstanceManager Setup**

```
mReactInstanceManager = ReactInstanceManager.builder()
        .addPackage(new MyReactPackage())
        .setCurrentActivity(this)
        // other settings
        .build();
```

Comment: Hey, thank you, @mpkuth. Unfortunately (fortunately?), I don't use React Native anymore but I'm sure your answer will be useful for someone else.

Comment: I had to use a different name for the finish method

Comment: hello @mpkuth,  can you help me find an idea how can I do the opposite, I mean, I want to open a react native component from the Native java code