# Android splash screen / launch screen also shows when keyboard is resizing

Tags: android, android-layout, react-native, splash-screen, launch-screen

I have a blue image as splash screen for startup.

However inside my app when an open keyboard is closed it shows the background imagine of the splash screen for a brief second which looks very weird.

windowSoftInputMode is set to

`android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"`

I think `adjustResize` is right.

What could I do to solve the problem? Why is the splash screen even in the background?

Comment: you should perhaps make sure that the splash activity shouldn't be present in the activity stack after its work is over.

Answer (score 3):

No clue if you do this already, but for activities like a splash screen where you only use it once and returning isn't wanted, remember to call `finish()`. If you finish the activity, it will not be in the activity stack. Try adding `finish()` after the intent that takes you away from the splash screen

Comment: Thanks. I am using react-native:

Just has a 
```
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
```

in the manifest file and another xml for the launch screen config. I will try to figure this out

Comment: You still need to call finish. CHeck [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33352553/call-methods-from-the-activity-class-react-native-android)